# QMenu with CSS : Remove the indent when changing background-color

Tags: qt, qtstylesheets, qmenu

My menus in my application looks something like this :

[image: Before adding CSS]

But I want the menu items to have a different background color. So I tried adding :

```
QMenu::item:selected {
    background-color:green;
    color:white;

}
```

And now it looks like this :

[image: After adding CSS]

Notice that when I hover my mouse over the menu, there is some sort of 'unalignment' with the menu items. How can I resolve this issue?. Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: I have tried the stylesheet and it does not generate this issue, you have used another stylesheet, I have tested it in Qt 5.9, what version do you use?

Comment: Try to adjust padding/margin of menu items.

Comment: @eyllanesc I used Qt 5.8 and on my stylesheet, their is another menu related thing, which is QMenuBar::item:selected{background-color:green; color:white} to make the headers in the menubar green, wonder if that does anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The built-in style system and CSS are mutually exclusive. If you're styling a control via CSS, you must **style all of it**. By applying CSS to one style of a menu item, you've lost the rest of the built-in style, and your CSS must then take care of all aspects of the styling. I.e. you need to style also non-selected items!